# C++ Multilevel inheritance / polymorphism

Tags: c++

I'm currently working on my C++ assignment and I'm working through polymorphism and I keep getting error messages. Would appreciate any help. Thanks in advance!

The assignment uses a shape inheritance hierarchy that looks like this:

```
Circle
Two Dimensional Shape
Cylnder
Shape
Three Dimensional Shape
```

Below is the error messages I'm getting.

> 1>Circle.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall TwoDimensionalShapes::TwoDimensionalShapes(void)" (??0TwoDimensionalShapes@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: __thiscall Circle::Circle(void)" (??0Circle@@QAE@XZ)
>
> 1>Cylinder.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall ThreeDimensionalShapes::ThreeDimensionalShapes(void)" (??0ThreeDimensionalShapes@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: __thiscall Cylinder::Cylinder(void)" (??0Cylinder@@QAE@XZ)

I'm pretty much done with my program but I'm not sure where the problems are coming from.

Here's my source code:

```
#include "Cylinder.h"
#include "Circle.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // next line commented out because will now cause compile error
    //  Shape    shpeObj;  // instantiate a Shape object

    cout << "The Shape object count is: " << Shape::getObjectCount() << '\n';

    Circle   crclObj;  // instantiate a Circle object
    Cylinder cyldObj;  // instantiate a Cylinder object

    // Count will be 2 in statement below because a Shape object is contained
    //     within each Circle and Cylinder object.
    cout << "The Shape object count is: " << Shape::getObjectCount() << "\n";

    Shape * shpePtr = &cyldObj;   // declare a Shape pointer
    // and have it point to the Cylinder object
    Shape & shpeRef = cyldObj;  // declare a Shape reference
    // and have it reference the Cylinder object

    // The above 2 statments are ok because a derived class object IsA base class object!

    // No additional objects created, so the count is still the same.
    cout << "The Shape object count is: " << Shape::getObjectCount() << "\n";

    // Dynamically create 2 objects
    Shape * shpePtr2 = new Circle;
    Shape & shpeRef2 = *new Cylinder;

    // The count should now be 4
    cout << "The Shape object count is: " << Shape::getObjectCount() << "\n";

    // Now destroy the 2 dynamically created objects!
    delete shpePtr2;
    delete &shpeRef2;

    //The count should now be 2 again.
    cout << "The Shape object count is: " << Shape::getObjectCount() << "\n\n";

    /*  Can no longer test Shape class, since it is now an Abstract Base Class (ABC)
    // Test Shape class

    shpeObj.setNoOfSides(0);

    cout << "The number of sides   is: " << shpeObj.getNoOfSides() << "\n\n";
    cout << "The area   of shpeObj is: " << shpeObj.Area() << '\n';
    cout << "The volume of shpeObj is: " << shpeObj.Volume() << "\n\n\n";
    */

    // Test Circle class

    crclObj.setRadius(3.0);

    cout << fixed << setprecision(4); // force use of decimal point and 4 digits of 
    //     precision after the decimal place
    cout << "The radius of crclObj is: " << crclObj.getRadius() << "\n\n";
    cout << "The number of sides   is: " << crclObj.getNoOfSides() << "\n\n";
    cout << "The area   of crclObj is: " << crclObj.Area() << '\n';
    // next line no longer valid in my solution for this assignment
    //cout << "The volume of crclObj is: " << crclObj.Volume() << "\n\n\n";

    // Test Cylinder class

    cyldObj.setRadius(5.5);
    cyldObj.setHeight(2.5);

    cout << "The radius of cyldObj is: " << cyldObj.getRadius() << '\n';
    cout << "The height of cyldObj is: " << cyldObj.getHeight() << "\n\n";
    cout << "The number of sides   is: " << cyldObj.getNoOfSides() << "\n\n";
    cout << "The area   of cyldObj is: " << cyldObj.Area() << '\n';
    cout << "The volume of cyldObj is: " << cyldObj.Volume() << "\n\n";

    return 0;
}

    #pragma once
    
    class Shape
    {
    public:
        Shape(void);  //constructor
        ~Shape(void); //destructor
    
        void setNoOfSides(const int &);  // set the # of sides
        int getNoOfSides() const;        // get the # of sides
    
        static int getObjectCount();     // get the object count
    
        virtual double Area() const = 0;     // calculate and return area
        // now a pure virtual function
        virtual double Volume() const;   // calculate and return volume
    
    protected:
        int mNoOfSides; // represents # of sides in Shape object
        static int mObjectCount; // a static member - counts the # of Shape 
        //          objects currently instantiated
        // Only one of these instantiated for the whole class!
    };

    #pragma once
    #include "Shape.h"
    class TwoDimensionalShapes :public Shape
    
    {
    public:
        TwoDimensionalShapes(void);  //constructor
    
        virtual double Area() const = 0; // area of 2D shape
    
    };

    #pragma once
    #include "Shape.h"
    
    class ThreeDimensionalShapes :public Shape
    {
    public:
        ThreeDimensionalShapes(void); // constructor
    
        virtual double Area() const = 0; // area of 3D shape
        virtual double Volume() const = 0; // volume of 3D shape
    
    };

#pragma once
#include "TwoDimensionalShapes.h"

class Circle :public TwoDimensionalShapes
{
public:
    Circle(void); // constructor

    void setRadius(const double &);  //set the radius
    double getRadius() const;  // get the radius

    virtual double Area() const override;  // overrides Area() method of TwoDimensionalShapes class

protected:
    const static double pi; // Static member used in calculations
    // Only one of these instantiated for the whole class!
    double mRadius;  // member used to represent radius

};

    #pragma once
    #include "ThreeDimensionalShapes.h"
    
    class Cylinder :public ThreeDimensionalShapes
    {
    public:
        Cylinder(void); // constructor
    
        void setHeight(const double &); // set the height
        double getHeight() const; // get the height
        void setRadius(const double &);  //set the radius
        double getRadius() const;  // get the radius
    
        virtual double Area() const override;    // overrides Area()   method of ThreeDimensionalShapes class
        virtual double Volume() const override;  // overrides Volume() method of ThreeDimensionalShapes  class
    
    protected:
        const static double pi; // Static member used in calculations
        // Only one of these instantiated for the whole class!
        double mHeight;  // member used to represent height
    
        double mRadius;
    };

#include "Circle.h"

// init static data member
const double Circle::pi = 3.141592654;  // init. static member

// constructor 
Circle::Circle(void)
    :mRadius(0.0)
{
    setNoOfSides(0);
}

// used to set value for mRadius member
void Circle::setRadius(const double & setVal)
{
    if (setVal > 0.0) // Make sure input is a valid value
    {
        this->mRadius = setVal;
    }

    // otherwise just leave set to original value
}

// used to return current value of mRadius member
double Circle::getRadius(void) const
{
    return this->mRadius;
}

// used top calculate and return area.
double Circle::Area(void) const
{
    return Circle::pi * this->mRadius * this->mRadius;
}

#include "Cylinder.h"

// init static data member
const double Cylinder::pi = 3.141592654;  // init. static member

// constructor
Cylinder::Cylinder(void)
    :mHeight(0.0)
{
    this->setNoOfSides(3);   // Why not init. this member in MIL ???
}

// used to set mHeight member
void Cylinder::setHeight(const double & setVal)
{
    if (setVal > 0.0)  // Make sure input is a valid value
    {
        this->mHeight = setVal;
    }

    // otherwise just leave set to original value
}

// used to return current value of mHeight member
double Cylinder::getHeight(void) const
{
    return this->mHeight;
}

// used to set value for mRadius member
void Cylinder::setRadius(const double & setVal)
{
    if (setVal > 0.0) // Make sure input is a valid value
    {
        this->mRadius = setVal;
    }

    // otherwise just leave set to original value
}

// used to return current value of mRadius member
double Cylinder::getRadius(void) const
{
    return this->mRadius;
}

// used to caluclate and return area
double Cylinder::Area(void) const
{
    double TwoPiR = 2.0 * Cylinder::pi * this->mRadius;
    return (TwoPiR * this->mRadius) + (TwoPiR * this->mHeight);
}

// used to claculate and return volume
double Cylinder::Volume(void) const
{
    return Cylinder::pi * this->mRadius * this->mRadius * this->mHeight;
}

#include "Shape.h"

// init static data memeber
int Shape::mObjectCount = 0;

// constructor
Shape::Shape(void)
    :mNoOfSides(1)
{
    ++Shape::mObjectCount;
}

// desstructor
Shape::~Shape(void)
{
    --Shape::mObjectCount;
}

// used to set mNoOfSides member
void Shape::setNoOfSides(const int & setVal)
{
    if (setVal > 0)
    {
        this->mNoOfSides = setVal;
    }

    // otherwise just leave set to original value
}

// used to return current value of mNoOfSides member
int Shape::getNoOfSides() const
{
    return this->mNoOfSides;
}

// used to return current value of mObjectCount static member
int Shape::getObjectCount()
{
    return Shape::mObjectCount;
}

/* no longer required to be implemented now that it is a
pure virtual function

// used to calculate and return area
double Shape::Area(void) const
{
return 0.0;
}

*/

// used to calculate and return volume
double Shape::Volume(void) const
{
    return 0.0;
}
```

Comment: Looks like you forgot to implement a couple of constructors that you declared. (You should just leave the declarations out, as the abstract bases have no data members.)

Comment: Thanks! Yea I forgot to provide a constructor implementation for my TwoDimensionalShapes and ThreeDimensionalShapes classes.

Comment: avoid posting such long snippets of code. Just show minimum code that can reproduce your problem.

Comment: that is a way to find linker(build) errors if you dont understand the errormessage: while trying to make a minimal code sample to show the error, chances are you find out what went wrong.

Comment: thanks! will make a note of that

Answer (score 1):

OK I figured it out now. I forgot to provide a constructor implementation for my TwoDimensionalShapes and ThreeDimensionalShapes classes. Silly mistake.